# How can I save the whole classes (Stored in HashMap) with all their variables to the files?

Tags: java, swing, serialization, hashmap, jpanel

I have a HashMap like this: `HashMap<String, JPanel>`

I have 6 types of pages. All of them extend JPanel.

I save this HashMap full of JPanels to a text File (.txt) using the code below:

```
public static void writeJTreeToFile(final File f) {
  //serialization
    final FileOutputStream file;
    try {
        // write HashMap to file
        File hashF = new File(f.toString().replace(".txt", "HashMap.txt"));
        final FileOutputStream hashFile = new FileOutputStream(hashF);
        ObjectOutputStream hashOut = new ObjectOutputStream(hashFile);
        hashOut.writeObject(implMainPage.getHashMap());
        hashOut.close();

        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

And I read the HashMap from saved files using the code below:

```
public static void readJTreeFromFile(File f) {
    //deserialization
    final FileInputStream file;
    try {
        
        // read HashMap from file
        File hashF = new File(f.toString().replace(".txt", "HashMap.txt"));
        final FileInputStream hashFile = new FileInputStream(hashF);
        ObjectInputStream hashIn = new ObjectInputStream(hashFile);
        HashMap<String, JPanel> hashMap = (HashMap<String, JPanel>)hashIn.readObject();
        implMainPage.setHashMap(hashMap);
        hashIn.close();
        
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

        }catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        } 
}
```

The panels can be displayed but the functions in the actionListeners of JButtons are not executed when pressed.

I believe when the JPanels are saved, it just saves the appearence of them, not the whole class.

How can I save the whole classes with all their variables to the files?

Comment: 1) Don't store the containers and actions, store the state of those, or the model that represents their content. 2) Use an appropriate file extension when serializing. A `txt` file is for text, while an appropriate extension for serialized objects is `obj`.

Comment: I have a lot of different components from each other. Do I have to store each state individually or is there a way to get the states or models of all the components in a JPanel. What is the difference btw ".obj" and ".txt"? Don't they do pretty much the same thing?

Comment: *"Do I have to store each state individually or is there a way to get the states or models of all the components in a JPanel."* You might be able to create an API that traverses all the fields in a panel and extracts the data from controls like check boxes and text components, but it would not be a trivial task, and whether that is easier than hand coding a solution would depend on the number of panels & complexity of that they contain. *"What is the difference btw ".obj" and ".txt"?"* Have you ever double clicked a file containing serialized objects but marked as `txt`? ..

Comment: .. What do you see in the default system text editor? Does it **look** like text or as though it might sensibly be edited in that app?

Comment: You are right: When I clicked on ".txt" file, I saw gibberish. I just wondered if the program behaves differently when ".obj" used. For my edification, I tried now and saw no difference. Thanks for the answer I will try to write the API for traversing the fields. I know I know "There is no try. Do or do not." :D

Comment: After traversing, getting and saving all the components in panel, how can I set the components when loading a panel?

Comment: *"all the components"* Nope: you've already gone wrong. It is the *state  / content* of the components that should be saved. But this 'develop an API' approach is worthy of it's own question thread(s). It cannot be addressed in comments. BTW - I just noticed the reference to a `JTree`. It is the `TreeModel` the code should be trying to serialize, not the tree component.

Comment: *"Let us continue this discussion in chat."* No thanks. I realize it was the site software that suggested that, but I reserve 'chat' for FB, and there I don't discuss tech issues.

Comment: I built models for all of the components and saved those models as you said. It worked. Thank you for your help Andrew.